# How to change php form input into a number using JavaScript and?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on creating a website that can translate a base 10 number into Binary for extra credit in a class I am taking.

My website URL is: `http://loganf.tynken.com`. My goal is to have the user enter a number into a form, for that number to become a string in a `<h4>` tag, and to be used by JavaScript to take the string, make it a number, and to then use more code to show the binary number on the screen.

I'm having trouble getting the string into a number.

The JavaScript shown here is now my final product, but a way to try to make the number appear.

```js
    var base10, base2, v2_0, v2_1, v2_2, v2_3, v2_4, v2_5, v2_6, v2_7,
    v2_8, v2_9, v2_10, v2_11, v2_12;
    base10 = document.getElementById('base10');
    base2 = document.getElementById('base2');
    v2_0 = 1;
    v2_1 = 2;
    v2_2 = 4;
    v2_3 = 8;

    function assignvarbinaryvalue() {
    var binaryNumber = Number(base10);
    var newEl = document.createElement('h4');
    var newText = document.createTextNode(binaryNumber);
    newEl.appendChild(newText);
    var position = document.getElementById('binaryID');
    position.appendChild(newEl);
    }
```

```html
<h1>Binary Translator</h1>
<p><div id="base10"><?php echo $_GET['base10']; ?></div><p id="binaryID"></p></p>
```

Comment: I could take exception with a lot of things.  My suggestion to you however would be to simplify things a bit, for instance maybe by only go up to 2 to the 4th to begin with.  Break it down and see where you're going wrong.  Do you use Chrome developer tools and look in the console for any errors?

Comment: Unrelated but why do you have an `h4` coming after an `h1`? Don't use headings because of the way they render the font, use them because you need sections of a certain ranking.

Comment: I am not using chrome. Thank you for the advice on simplifying things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var base10 = document.getElementById('base10');
var base2 = document.getElementById('base2');
document.getElementById('submit').onclick=function() {

var number=parseInt(base10.value);
 base2.value=decimalToBinary(number);
  
}

function decimalToBinary(n){
    var binaryNumberStr = "";
    var binaryNumber=0;
    var step=0;

    while (Math.pow(2, step)<n)
    {
       step+=1;
    }
    for(var i=step; i>=0; i--){
    
    var c=Math.floor(n/Math.pow(2, i))
   
    n-=Math.pow(2, i)*c;
    binaryNumber+=Math.pow(2, i)*c;
    binaryNumberStr+=c;
    }
    //binaryNumberStr+=(n-binaryNumber)
    return binaryNumberStr;
}
```

```html
<p>Number:</p>
  <input type="text" id="base10" name="base10" size="15" maxlength="30">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  <input type="text" id="base2" name="base2" disabled size="15" maxlength="30">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert string into number you can just use javascript function

```
parseInt()
```

Comment: That didn't change anything either. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You are not grabbing the value:

```
var base10, base2, v2_0, v2_1, v2_2, v2_3, v2_4, v2_5, v2_6, v2_7, v2_8, v2_9, v2_10, v2_11, v2_12;
base10 = document.getElementById('base10');
base2 = document.getElementById('base2');
v2_0 = 1;
v2_1 = 2;
v2_2 = 4;
v2_3 = 8;
v2_4 = 16;
//v2_5 = 32;
//v2_6 = 64;
//v2_7 = 128;
//v2_8 = 256;
//v2_9 = 512;
//v2_10 = 1024;
//v2_11 = 2084;
//v2_12 = 4096;

function assignvarbinaryvalue() {
    var binaryNumber = parseInt(base10.innerHTML);
    var newEl = document.createElement('h4');
    var newText = document.createTextNode(binaryNumber);
    newEl.appendChild(newText);
    var position = document.getElementById('binaryID');
    position.appendChild(newEl);
}
assignvarbinaryvalue()
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do you think there could another problem? Thanks!

Comment: Also I saw your demo - you're not calling your function either. Updated answer with full code.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. It still has no effect.